# Do another pass through a list of things

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is it right to ask someone to "do another pass through the questions" when you want them to take another look/check/examination at a few questions?

For example:

> Bob: I think we are done now, right?
>
> John: We are mostly done, Bob; before you go, could you please do another pass through the question we discussed earlier?

Answer (score 1):

Your question and the example do not have the same meaning so I would have a different answer in both cases. Your question is about taking a pass through a list. Your example is about taking a pass through a question.

For me you can pass through a list but not a question. It should be clear through context what taking a pass through means. For example, if it is a to-do list, taking a pass through the list might mean marking off the items that are done. I’m not 100% sure what taking a pass through a list of questions means. If you are preparing for a meeting where you plan to ask the questions, a pass through might mean checking that they are relevant and valuable. If you have had a go at answering a list of questions previously, another pass through might be checking that the answers are answering the questions asked. This will probably be known through similar tasks previously performed.